# Assuming that R and S are integral domains, determine all idempotents in the ring $R \times S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Assuming that $R$ and $S$ are integral domains, determine all idempotents in the ring $R \times S$.

Hint：An element $e$ of a ring is called an idempotent if $e^2 = e$.

Comment: I feel slightly guilty for giving you a downvote, but it just seems like you have put literally $0$ effort into solving the problem yourself. This is not a hard question, as you would well appreciate if you had spent 15 mins toying with it on a bit of paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(r,s)^2=(r^2,s^2)$. For this to be idempotent both $r$ and $s$ must be idempotent. Now, if $t$ is idempotent, then $t^2-t=t(t-1)=0$, so unless $t=0,1$ $t$ is a zero divisor. By the integral domain assumption it follows that $r,s\in \{0,1\}$. Thus there are four idempotent elements.